# Cross compiling gcc 6.2 for QNX

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling, qnx

I'm trying to cross compile GCC or clang for qnx and I am not able to find any good set of instructions that explain cross compiling to other operating systems. I already have access to qnx and a GCC compiler version 4.7 for the target.

I've tried reading http://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/ and wasn't successful. I keep running into this error:

```
checking dynamic linker characteristics... ldqnx.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for shl_load... configure: error: Link tests are not allowed after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES.
Makefile:11454: recipe for target 'configure-target-libstdc++-v3' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-target-libstdc++-v3] Error 1
```

I want to compile the latest stable GCC. The host machine is an x86_64 linux. The target is i486-pc-nto-qnx6.6.0. Any ideas?